# Fixing jsDelivr "multiple files" approach that breaks CSS' image URI's

Tags: css, cdn, jsdelivr

`jsDelivr` ( http://jsdelivr.com ) has *Multiple File* mode:

- https://github.com/jsdelivr/jsdelivr#load-multiple-files-with-single-http-request

Problem is, libraries with CSS such as [Gritter](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.gritter/1.7.4/css/jquery.gritter.css) and [Font Awesome](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/fontawesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css) use images in their interface components.

This leads to `404` errors when doing something like this:

```
//cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/jquery@2.1.0,bootstrap@3.1.1,summernote@0.5.0,mousewheel@3.1.6,jquery.timeago@1.3.0,jquery.gritter@1.7.4,jquery.unveiljs@1.0,jquery.waypoints@2.0.2,bootstrap.tagsinput@0.3.9,bootstrap.datepicker-fork@1.3.0,jquery.jqote2@0.9.8,portal@1.1.1
```

[image]

### How can we use multiple libraries off the one CDN pageload, but change the paths CSS files reference to use the appropriate jsDeliver.net URI?

Is this a job for post-processing CSS in-browser, by jQuery or pure JavaScript, or is one forever doomed to one CDN pageload per CSS file referencing images, plus one remaining pageload for the CDN served CSS without image references?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unfortunately /g/ does not work with files that contain relative paths.

You can load this kind of files individually and use /g/ for the rest of them normally.